# Cycles with not full additions, find the value of this expression/

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Given `x` and `n`, sum `1 / (x + (1/x))` n times and print the result.

This is my attempt:

```
x = int(input("enter the x"))
n=int(input("enter the n"))
start = 1/x
Endnum = 1/(x+start)*n
print(Endnum)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). It would help clarify your question if you added an example input and expected output, and described why your code fails to meet expectations. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: You are to do `1/x -> 1 / (x + 1 / x) -> 1 / ( 1 / (x +  1 / x) ->... -> 1 / (1 / (1 .... ( 1 / (x + 1 / x)))...). Nothing undoable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly:

Initialise `sum_x` with 0 and then use a `for` loop to add to add `1/(x + add_in_denominator)` to it `n` times.

```
x = int(input("enter the x"))
n = int(input("enter the n"))
add_in_denominator = 1/x
sum_x = 0
for i in range(n):
    sum_x += 1/(x + add_in_denominator)
print(sum_x)
```

Comment: It's not `i` you have to add, but the previous value you got

Comment: @sudden_appearance right, I missed that. fixed my answer, thanks!

Comment: There is also a small typo, `print(sum)` -> `print(sum_x)`

Comment: @sudden_appearance right, fixed again. Thanks :)

Comment: @sudden_appearance Reading the question again, I'm not sure if the action should be to add `1/(x+ sum_x)` or `1/(x + 1/x)`.

Comment: Oh wow, It seems like you are right:/ My fault

Comment: @sudden_appearance No worries :)